# Would it be useful for a programmer to get qualified in Prince2

Tags: project-management, prince2

Even if the programmer wasn't going to perform the function of project manager, would there be any benefit on a small team of one of the devs being Prince2 qualified?

Comment: I have found it very useful. 1) there are more job opportunities 2)you understand why Management ask all those dumb questions 3)you may actually do some of those many things which are part of delivering a product that aren't programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Speaking as someone who works as a developer, as is fully prince2 qualified, I have found it somewhat useful in assisting managing projects.

Prince2 is I would say, like the abstract class that other methodlogies such as agile/scrum/waterfall can implement.  That's not to say that Prince2 is better or was first, just that is more of a conceptual framework that can be implemented in different ways. I would say it does cover all areas of project management and it is applied to other domains than software.

It is especially useful if you are working in prince2 organisation, but if you are not and have no plans to its usefulness is somewhat restricted.

My employer paid for my course, if it was my money or if I could back I would think twice before doing it.  A scrum master qualification may be more useful ... as it is "hotter" and focussed on software development.

Answer (score 3):

The Prince2 qualification itself is only really of use to those who want to be professional project managers, but understanding the *content* of it and its *meaning* is quite reasonable for the more senior members of dev team. (It would probably help junior members too, but they're busy learning other important things too. Don't overload!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Managing dev projects is still project managment so the Prince skills will still be usefull. It dosent cover all aspects of software project managment so I recomend you pick up a book on agile after.